# PHP Mysqli Select values from multi table

Tags: mysql

I create 2 database table , 1 is with customer order and 1 is with stock shop and website.

I want to show in order the stock. but i don't success to make the select DB with stock.

```
  <?php
                            $rowCount = count($_GET['bid_id']);
                            for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++) {
                                $result = $DBcon->query("SELECT c.*, SUM(s.stoc) as stoc, SUM(s.stoc_rezervat) as stoc_rezervat, s.sku FROM comenzi_okazii AS c LEFT JOIN stocuri_mentor AS s ON c.nume_produs LIKE s.sku WHERE bid_id='$bid_id'");
                                while($row[$i] = $result->fetch_array()) {?>
                                    <tr class="titlerow">
                                        <td id="<?php echo $bid_id; ?>"><button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete' id="<?php echo $row[$i]['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Cod Produs este Gol')" placeholder="Cod Produs" style="width:100%" type='text' id='cod_produs_1' name='nume_produs[]' value="<?php echo $row[$i]['nume_produs']; ?>"/></td>
                                        <td style='width:100px'><input class="form-control qty_1" placeholder="Cantitate" style="width:100%" type="text" id="qty_1" name='qty[]' value="<?php echo $row[$i]['qty']; ?>"/></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Nume" style="width:100%" type='text' id='nume_1' name='nume_ales[]' value="<?php echo $row[$i]['nume_ales']; ?>"/></td>
                                        <td style='width:100px'><input class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Stoc" style="width:100%" type='text' id='stoc_1' name='stoc_magazin[]' value="<?php echo $row[$i]['stoc']; ?>"/></td>
                                        <td style='width:100px'><input class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Rezervat" style="width:100%" type='text' id='stoc_rez_1' name='stoc_rezervat[]' value="<?php echo $row[$i]['stoc_rezervat'];?>"/></td>
```

But don't work the stock or show the information only 1 product or hide all product and show only one.

Structure from DB `comenzi_okazii` saves the products that are in the order.

```
id - AI 
bid_id - Number of Order
nume_produs - Product Code (SKU)
qty - Quantity of product in order
price - Price of Product
```

Structure from DB `stocuri_mentor` this my management program save the stock of

```
shop.
id - AI
sku - Product Code(SKU)
stoc - Product Stock
stoc_rezervat - Reserved stock
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregate functions in the SELECT list (`SUM()`, without a `GROUP BY` clause means the query will return *one* row.

(Other relational databases would throw an error, with the non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list not appearing in the GROUP BY clause. A non-standard extension specific to MySQL allows the query to execute, without throwing an error.)

Add a `GROUP BY` clause to get a row for each distinct value of an expression (or set of expressions)

For example:

```
  SELECT c.*
       , SUM(s.stoc) AS stoc
       , SUM(s.stoc_rezervat) AS stoc_rezervat
       , s.sku
    FROM comenzi_okazii c
    LEFT
    JOIN stocuri_mentor s
      ON c.nume_produs LIKE s.sku
   WHERE c.bid_id = 'somevalue'
   GROUP BY c.nume_produs
-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    -- *** add GROUP BY clause ***
```

Non-standard behavior of GROUP BY is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

---

SQL Injection vulnerability

It's not at all clear what value `$bid_id` contains, and whether that value is guaranteed to be "safe" to include in the text of SQL statement. The code pattern appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. We don't see `$bid_id` is returned from `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

The preferred pattern is to avoid including values in SQL text, and to instead use *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*

See also:

https://xkcd.com/327/

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

---

Comment: actually, since 5.7 mysql is also throwing this error

Comment: @YourCommonSense: MySQL 5.7 will throw an error because the default setting for `sql_mode` includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. The non-standard extension can be enabled by removing `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. (Earlier versions of MySQL will also throw an error if `sql_mode` includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Comment: Is the best answer :X Working .